Freezing the axis-labels on top of figure in R shiny
I have a renderGirafe that is very long. I want the user to be able to see the x-axis values (which are on top of figure) after scrolling down.
Here is a sample code. In this code, I want the user to still be able to see the years when he/she scrolls down. I'm pretty flexible with what type of plot to be generated, as long as it shows the labels when hovering the mouse over each block. Suggestions are welcome!
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)

ui <- fluidRow(girafeOutput("my_plot"))

server <- function(input, output){
  output$my_plot <- renderGirafe({
    
    data <- data.frame(
      letter = rep(c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters))),
      year = factor(rep_len(2000:2008, 78)),
      value = floor(runif(78, 1, 6))
    )
    
    g <- ggplot(data) + 
      geom_tile_interactive(aes(x = year, y = letter, fill = value, tooltip = value)) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
      coord_fixed() +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 90,
        hjust = 0.5,
        vjust = 0,
        size = 17
      )) 
    
    girafe(ggobj = g,  
           options = list(opts_sizing(rescale = F)),
           width_svg = 20,
           height_svg = 50
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


With plotly, you can scroll the y axis when hovering it, see the cursor in the image:

Users have to know that and there is no apparent scroll bar (a "rangeslider" would have done the job but this is not available for the y axis) so that is not ideal, but the result is still achieved.
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidRow(
  plotlyOutput("my_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$my_plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    data <- data.frame(
      letter = rep(c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters))),
      year = factor(rep_len(2000:2008, 78)),
      value = floor(runif(78, 1, 6))
    )

    g <- ggplot(data) + 
      geom_tile(aes(x = year, y = letter, fill = value), show.legend = F) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
      coord_fixed() +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 90,
        hjust = 0.5,
        vjust = 0,
        size = 17
      )) 

    # adjust the height to your needs:
    ggplotly(g, height = 5000) %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Within girafe:
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)

library(shiny)


ui <- fluidRow(girafeOutput("my_plot"))

server <- function(input, output){
  output$my_plot <- renderGirafe({
    
    data <- data.frame(
      letter = rep(c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters))),
      year = factor(rep_len(2000:2008, 78)),
      value = floor(runif(78, 1, 6))
    )
    
    g <- ggplot(data) + 
      geom_tile_interactive(
        aes(x = year, y = letter, fill = value, 
            tooltip = purrr::map(paste0(
              "<b>my letter</b>: ", letter ,
              "<br><b>my value</b>: ", as.character(sprintf("%.3f",value)) ,
              "<br><b>my year</b>: ", as.character(year) 
            ), shiny::HTML)# htmltools::HTML 
        )
      ) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
      coord_fixed() +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 90,
        hjust = 0.5,
        vjust = 0,
        size = 17
      )) 
    
    girafe(ggobj = g,  
           options = list(opts_sizing(rescale = F)),
           width_svg = 20,
           height_svg = 50
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Within ggplotly
(same as julien.leroux5, except not automatic, customized):

In aes: text, not other name of variable
In ggplotly: tooltip= "text"

library(purrr)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
library(shiny)

library(plotly)


ui <- fluidRow(
  plotlyOutput("my_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$my_plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    data <- data.frame(
      letter = rep(c(LETTERS, letters, paste0(LETTERS, letters))),
      year = factor(rep_len(2000:2008, 78)),
      value = floor(runif(78, 1, 6))
    )
    
    g <- ggplot(
      data,
      aes(
        text=purrr::map(paste0(
          "<b>my letter</b>: ", letter ,
          "<br><b>my value</b>: ", as.character(sprintf("%.3f",value)) ,
          "<br><b> my year</b>: ", as.character(year) 
        ), shiny::HTML)  # htmltools::HTML
      )
      
    ) + 
      geom_tile(aes(x = year, y = letter, fill = value), show.legend = F) + 
      scale_x_discrete(position = "top") + 
      coord_fixed() +
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
        angle = 90,
        hjust = 0.5,
        vjust = 0,
        size = 17
      )) 
    
    # adjust the height to your needs:
    ggplotly(g, 
             height = 5000,
             tooltip= "text"
    ) %>% 
      layout(xaxis = list(side = "top"))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

